# Disable Infinispan WARN logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, infinispan, spring-cache

i am using infispan in distributed mode which works fine, the only problem is, it prints a lot of logs and messes up the log files. below is a common line that gets printed.

```
WARN [jgroups-6,batch-pdcr-app-6c8fcd799c-fhmf8-35894] UDP: JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster recon-infinispan (our cluster is ISPN). Sender was 021f21a7-4434-0509-f6bb-b3451f0c98d5 (received 33 identical messages from 021f21a7-4434-0509-f6bb-b3451f0c98d5 in the last 60012 ms)
```

how do i disable this logging?

below is the cache configuration.

```
         @Bean
         @Primary
            public EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager() {
                return new DefaultCacheManager(getGlobalConfiguration());
            }
        
            private GlobalConfiguration getGlobalConfiguration() {
                GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfigurationBuilder = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder();
                globalConfigurationBuilder.transport().defaultTransport().initialClusterSize(1);
                return globalConfigurationBuilder.build();
            }
    
    
     @Bean
        public Cache<String, String> interfaceCache(DefaultCacheManager cacheManager) {
            return this.buildCache(ProducerConstants.BATCH_PRODUCER_INTERFACE_CACHE, cacheManager, interfaceCacheExpiringEvictingConfig(cacheManager));
        }
    
        private Configuration interfaceCacheExpiringEvictingConfig(DefaultCacheManager cacheManager) {
    
    
            ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            confBuilder.expiration().lifespan(24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            confBuilder.memory().maxCount(100).whenFull(EvictionStrategy.REMOVE);
            confBuilder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC);
    
            return confBuilder.build();
        }

private <K, V> Cache<K, V> buildCache(String cacheName, DefaultCacheManager cacheManager, Configuration configuration) {

        cacheManager.defineConfiguration(cacheName, configuration);
        Cache<K, V> cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
        cache.addListener(new CacheListener());
        return cache;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 clusters using the same ports and the traffic conflicts with each other. I would recommend using different ports in one of the clusters. The properties `jgroups.bind.port` and `jgroups.mcast_port` can be used to configure the JGroups ports.

Comment: why are these two clusters? i am using cash node DIST_SYNC. isnt this supposed to run one cluster?